# Qt Dynamically load MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, qt, dll, deployment, driver

I have no experience with deploying apps. I started manually (by copying release.exe to target PC and 1-by-1 resolving it's DLL dependencies). I've ran into "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded" wall and I'm stuck now.
I tried starting anew with the help of `windeployqt`, it compiled a nice set of files and directories, and still that same error.
I tried checking arch of dlls with notepad hack and tried redownloading `libmysql.dll` from different places. I have rebuilt `qsqlmysql.dll` manually (only to learn I really needed `libmysql.dll`). I added project folder to PATH variable, still to no avail.
I've heard that `Dependecy Walker` might help, but it didn't, it only warned me that there were errors finding some files, to quote,

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

So I'm begging for a method to learn where to put the DLL. Or just for a path, regarding that the app, dlls and everithing is 32-bit.

P.S. I've just learned that if I try to statically link that .lib file (which is by the way 30KB in size compared to .dll's 4MB) the build is successful but it changes *nothing*. DLL still needed

Comment: Can you show how its linked in your .pro file

Comment: @MohammadKanan LIBS += "C:\Users\user\projfolder\libmysql.lib". Also, I'd prefer to avoid static linking, because it is obviously not the solution in this case (.lib file is useless). Please, help me resolve it the dynamic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the 32bit connector for MySQL from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/), then make a *dynamic* link to the lib, (*Project -> Add Library -> External -> Dynamic*), tick the platfrom you are working on; something like:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../mysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32/lib/ -llibmysql
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../mysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32/lib/ -llibmysqld

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../mysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../mysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32/include
```

Comment: still same message :( I've got almost exactly the code you've shown in .pro file. I moved both .a and .dll to be sure to the $PWD itself. And the driver still not loaded.

Comment: win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lmysql
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lmysqld

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mysql-con/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mysql-con/include

Comment: did you update the `.pro` manually ? have you seen my update on answer how to link dynamically

Comment: There is a difference, yours is `lmysqld` , I expect `llibmysql`, link to the file `libmysql.lib` not `libmysql.dll`

Comment: under `<connector_path/lib/`

Comment: tried with llibmysql, didn't work still. build successful, same error

Comment: After you run `windeployqt` check if the file `libmysql.dll` is copied to your deployment folder, if not copy it, it should work.

Comment: I checked, it's not copied by windeployqt. I copied manually and it didn't help. I downloaded the connector again, still "Driver not loaded"

Comment: if you can establish MySQL db connection from Qt Creator, then setting should be ok, when I want to deploy I copy the dll to root folder with .exe file. Now I believe you might have _another_ issue?

Comment: I learned that -lmysqlcppconn is also required. However, additionaly linking it didn't help. I can agree I can have another issue, but how to even detect it? I feel so stuck :\